# MongoDb TTL index for non ISO date format

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, ttl

Below is my sample Json message and it has Timestamp format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD (eg 2015-08-18T22:43:01-04:00)

Also I have a TTL index setup for 30 days but my data is not getting removed. I know that Mongodb uses ISODate("2015-09-03T14:21:30.177-04:00") kind format but is that absolutely necessary? What modification I can do in my index to get the TTL working.

We have millions of documents under multiple collections and we run of space every now and then.

JSON:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("55d3ed35817f4809e14e2"),
"AuditEnvelope" : {
    "TrackingInformation" : {
        "CorelationId" : "2703-4ce2-af68-47832462",
        "Timestamp" : "2015-08-18T22:43:01-04:00",
        "LogData" : {
            "msgDetailJson" : "[Somedata here]"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Index

```
 "1" : {
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "AuditEnvelope.TrackingInformation.Timestamp" : 1
    },
    "name" : "TTL",
    "ns" : "MyDB.MyColl",
    "expireAfterSeconds" : 2592000
},
```

MongoDB version : 3.0.1

Answer (score 4):

In order for the TTL clean-up process to work with a defined TTL index, the specified field **must** contain a [`Date` BSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#date) type, as is [covered in the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-ttl/#expiration-of-data) for TTL indexes.

> *If the indexed field in a document is not a [date](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-bson-types) or an array that holds a date value(s), the document will not expire.*

You will need to convert such strings as BSON dates. This is also a wise thing to do as the internal storage of a BSON Date is a numeric timestamp value, and this takes up a lot less storage than a string does.

Tranformation requires an update to "cast" to a date object. As a "one off" operation this probably best done through the MongoDB shell and with the use of [Bulk Operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) to minimize the network overhead when writing back the data.

```js
var bulk = db.MyColl.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    count = 0;

db.MyColl.find({ 
    "AuditEnvelope.TrackingInformation.Timestamp": { "$type": 2 } 
}).forEach(function(doc) {
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
        "$set": { 
            "AuditEnvelope.TrackingInformation.Timestamp":
                new Date(doc.AuditEnvelope.TrackingInformation.Timestamp)
        }
    });
    count++;

    if ( count % 1000 == 0 ) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.MyColl.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
});

if ( count % 1000 != 0 )
    bulk.execute();
```

Also not the BSON [**`$type`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) operation there is designed to match "strings", so even if you began a conversion or changed some code to start producing BSON date objects in the field then the query only picks up the "string" values for conversion.

Ideally you should drop the indexes already on the "Timestamp" fields and then re-create them after the update. This removes the overhead of writing to the index with the updated information. You can also set a [foreground index build](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-index/#additional-considerations) on the new index creation and this will also save some space in what the index itself consumes.